# Why do definitions have a space before the colon in NumPy docstring sections?

Tags: python, numpy, restructuredtext, docstring, numpydoc

[Numpy docstring guide](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html#sections) says:

> The colon must be preceded by a space, or omitted if the type is absent.

and gives an example:

```py
Parameters
----------
x : type
    Description of parameter `x`.
y
    Description of parameter `y` (with type not specified)
```

In the other hand,
[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#variable-annotations) literally says that a space before colon is wrong:

```py
# Wrong:

code:int  # No space after colon
code : int  # Space before colon
```

I know that this applies to the code, not to docstring, but still why not to be consistent?

### Question

What is motivation to put a space **before** the colon?

It seems to violate typographical rules and also the python convention (or at least intuition).

Comment: Found similar discussion on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/8vbhpi/in_python_docstrings_why_is_it_param_types_where/)

Comment: Why should it be consistent?  `numpy` developers are not Python ones.  Your pep8 case actually comes from the `annotations` addition, https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/ (from 2016).

Comment: Python docstring guide, PEP 257 uses two dashes, e.g. "real -- the real part (default 0.0)" (though that isn't as formally defined).

Comment: Related to the annotations is the PEP 484 type hints, which use the  nonspace convention, `(name: str)`.  These hints can be processed with tools like `mypy`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why a space before the colon?

Because in NumPy syntax definitions inside some [docstring sections](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html#sections) are made to coincide with the syntax of a reStructuredText [Definition List](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#definition-lists).
Notice the syntax is the exact same as reST markup specification for:

> **[Definition Lists](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#definition-lists)**
>
> Each definition list item contains a term, optional classifiers, and a definition. A term is a simple one-line word or phrase.  **Optional classifiers may follow the term on the same line, each after an inline " : " (space, colon, space).**
>
> ```
> Syntax diagram:
>
> +----------------------------+
> | term [ " : " classifier ]* |
> +--+-------------------------+--+
>    | definition                 |
>    | (body elements)+           |
>    +----------------------------+
> ```

Makes sense since numpydoc clearly states its intended compliance with PEP 257.

> **numpydoc docstring guide**
>
> **[Overview](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html#overview)**
>
> **We mostly follow the standard Python style conventions as described here:**
>
> - Docstring Conventions - PEP 257

And the PEP states its intent that docstrings should be written with reST constructs:

> [Abstract, PEP 287](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0287/#abstract)
>
> This PEP proposes that the reStructuredText markup be adopted as a standard markup format for structured plaintext documentation in Python docstrings

This can also be verified by quoting numpydoc contributor decisions as they were being taken, for example:

> [Issue #87](https://github.com/numpy/numpydoc/issues/87#issuecomment-328224912)
>
> Right now numpydoc format is actually valid rst (just with some special interpretation of certain markup constructs), e.g. the parameters field is a definition list where the type is a "classifier" (http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#definition-lists). I would argue that it is worthwhile to keep this property, which end-of-line backslashes do (they simply do not appear in the string itself), whereas the proposed "recognize indentation" syntax does not.

The same reasoning is mentioned in several places:

> [PR #107](https://github.com/numpy/numpydoc/pull/107)
>
> This probably falls under the category of "if it ain't broke, don't fix it", but I note that we're strangely using blockquotes for parameter listings instead of definition lists. **UPDATED: now this PR proposes to use definition lists by default, with a switch to use the legacy blockquotes.**

The specific rule of a space before the colon can be seen in the [numpydoc.validate.py](https://github.com/numpy/numpydoc/blob/ce6666ac82b6098b3d1b0909dc7a5eaef880b290/numpydoc/validate.py#L75) source code, and in the documentation:

> [Built-in Validation Checks](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validation.html#built-in-validation-checks)
>
> ```
> "PR10": 'Parameter "{param_name}" requires a space before the colon '
>        "separating the parameter name and type"
> ```

In conclusion, to write docstrings with reST (to be compliant with PEP 257) there aren't many list markup constructs in the [reST Body Elements](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#id49) to choose from. Definition lists are simply the best choice given its term/classifier syntax fits perfectly the name/type listing of Python objects.

---

---

Addressing an intuitive objection raised in the question:

> In the other hand, PEP8 literally says that a space before colon is wrong

Yes, but the function and variable annotations PEP 8 mentions do not refer to documentation strings (docstrings)! Those are intended for signatures and variable declarations.